# Parsing RSS in a Ruby on Rails project shows the html as inline html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rss

Im calling my feed with `<%= blog_feed %>` inside the view and have a little snippet in my helper.

```
require 'rss/1.0'
require 'rss/2.0'
require 'open-uri'

def blog_feed
    source = "http://www.domain.com/.rss" # url or local file
    content = "" # raw content of rss feed will be loaded here
    open(source) do |s| content = s.read end
    rss = RSS::Parser.parse(content, false)

    html = "<ul>"
    rss.items.first(3).each do |i|
    html << "<li><a href='#{i.link}'>#{i.title}</a></li>"
    end
    html << "</ul>"
    html


  end
```

It runs mostly the way i want. But the html is inline html. So i see li,ul and a hrefs on the website.

Any idea or suggestion?

best regards
denym

Answer (score 0):

The way you're processing and displaying the RSS in a view isn't the way I'd do it, but the quick answer is that you need to call **html_safe** for any HTML strings you build in this way.

This may be unsafe, as the incoming RSS data may have code in it that causes cross site security issues.  You can handle that by using the **sanitize** helper.  I think the *sanitize* helper automatically calls **html_safe** for you.

So, at the end of your **blog_feed** method, replace the *html* return value with:

```
  sanitize html
```

Check out the documentation for *sanitize* here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize